# Isolate a single column in a multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

Say for example you just queried a database and you recieved this 2D array.

```
$results = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'red'  , 'spin' =>  1),
    array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'green', 'spin' => -1),
    array('id' => 3, 'name' => 'blue' , 'spin' => .5)
);
```

I often find myself writing loops like this.

```
foreach($results as $result)
    $names[] = $result['name'];
```

My questions is does there exist a way to get this array $names without using a loop?  Using callback functions count as using a loop.

Here is a more generic example of getting every field.

```
foreach($results as $result)
    foreach($result as $key => $value)
        $fields[$key][] = $value;
```

Comment: FWIW, I have provided an answer to a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10660002/128346.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As of June 20th in PHP-5.5 there is a new function [array_column](https://www.php.net/array_column)

For example:

```
$records = array(
    array(
        'id' => 2135,
        'first_name' => 'John',
        'last_name' => 'Doe'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3245,
        'first_name' => 'Sally',
        'last_name' => 'Smith'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 5342,
        'first_name' => 'Jane',
        'last_name' => 'Jones'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 5623,
        'first_name' => 'Peter',
        'last_name' => 'Doe'
    )
);


$firstNames = array_column($records, 'first_name');
print_r($firstNames);
```

Will return

```
Array
(
    [0] => John
    [1] => Sally
    [2] => Jane
    [3] => Peter
)
```

There are even more examples in the above mentioned link.

Answer (score 14):

I voted @Devon's response up because there really isn't a way to do what you're asking with a built-in function.  The best you can do is write your own:

```
function array_column($array, $column)
{
    $ret = array();
    foreach ($array as $row) $ret[] = $row[$column];
    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: Bugs my that you haven't declared `ret`, even if you don't technically need to in PHP. (`$ret = array();`)

Comment: @Quentin please inform the answering user of anything you think is wrong about the answer rather than quietly correcting it.

Comment: That was Mark's comment about initializing `$ret`. I upvoted Mark's comment, offered a change in the answer with an explanation attached. I should have added a comment here as well?

Comment: Ironic that PHP had included a core function with exact same label `array_column()`..!! Were you involved?

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr haha, nope. Just a coincidence :)

Answer (score 7):

Starting PHP 5.3, you can use this pretty call with lambda function:

```php
$names = array_map(function ($v){ return $v['name']; }, $results);
```

This will return array sliced by 'name' dimension.

Comment: You may use additionally array_unique on returned sliced dimension to get unique names.

Answer (score 5):

Simply put, no.

You will need to use a loop or a callback function like [array_walk](https://www.php.net/function.array-walk).

Comment: This is no longer true. PHP 5.5 offers a built-in `array_column` function :)

Answer (score 2):

I did more research on this and found that ruby and prototype both have a function that does this called [array_pluck](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php#82256),[2](http://groups.google.ca/group/php.notes/browse_thread/thread/0ee4f31c6d98affe).  It's interesting that `array_map` has a second use that allows you to do the inverse of what i want to do here.  I also found a PHP [class](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/3565.html) someone is writing to emulate prototypes manipulation of arrays.

I'm going to do some more digging around and if I don't find anything else I'll work on a patch to submit to the internals@lists.php.net mailing list and see if they will  add array_pluck.

Answer (score 2):

For those of you that cannot upgrade to `PHP5.5` right now and need this function, here is an implementation of `array_column`.

```
function array_column($array, $column){
    $a2 = array();
    array_map(function ($a1) use ($column, &$a2){
        array_push($a2, $a1[$column]);
    }, $array);
    return $a2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a version of PHP before 5.5 and `array_column()`, you can use the official replacement in plain PHP:

https://github.com/ramsey/array_column

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you want

[array_uintersect_uassoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-uintersect-uassoc.php)

You would have to do something like this

```
$results = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'red'  , 'spin' =>  1),
    array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'green', 'spin' => -1),
    array('id' => 3, 'name' => 'blue' , 'spin' => .5)
);
$name = array_uintersect_uassoc( $results, array('name' => 'value')  , 0, "cmpKey");
print_r($name);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////
// FUNCTIONS
//////////////////////////////////////////////////
function cmpKey($key1, $key2) {
  if ($key1 == $key2) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
}
```

However, I don't have access to PHP5 so I haven't tested this.

Comment: This did not work for me in PHP5.  I got a Not a valid callback warning and an empty array.

Comment: It's failing because you have to pass a function not 0.  Even if i pass a function that always returns true or false to this i still don't get a valid answer.  You can't use array intersect because it's an array inside of an array.  You can use array_walk or array_map depending on return type.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
$tmp = array_flip($names);
$names = array_keys($tmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is fast function alternative of array_column()

```
if(!function_exists('array_column')) {
    function array_column($element_name) {
        $ele =   array_map(function($element) {
            return $element[$element_name];
        }, $a);
        return  $ele;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

other alternative

```
 function transpose(array $array): array
 {
     $out = array();
     foreach ($array as $rowkey => $row) {
        foreach ($row as $colkey => $col) {
                $out[$colkey][$rowkey] = $col;
         }
     }
        return $out;
 }

 function filter_columns(array $arr, string ...$columns): array
 {
     return array_intersect_key($arr, array_flip($columns));
 }
```

test

```
$results = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'red'  , 'spin' =>  1),
    array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'green', 'spin' => -1),
    array('id' => 3, 'name' => 'blue' , 'spin' => .5)
);

 var_dump(filter_columns(transpose($results),'name'));
 var_dump(filter_columns(transpose($results),'id','name'));
 var_dump(filter_columns(transpose($results),'id','spin'));
```