# Extract one value from a single multi-value row in an array

Tags: php, regex, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In PHP, is there a function that returns an array made up of the value of a key from an array of associative arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659875/in-php-is-there-a-function-that-returns-an-array-made-up-of-the-value-of-a-key)

Several values stored in one single row in an array like this:

```
Array
(
  [data] =>
     Duration: 1 Month
     Name: James Foo
     Category: Info Tech
)
```

---

### Question:

How could I extract and echo the values from [data] separately? i.e. display only `Category: Info Tech`?

Comment: the category etc should be in another array index

Comment: If all above is a value of element at index `data`, then how rows fo data are separated? Is there a space between them like `Duration: 1 Month Name: James Foo Category: Info Tech` or is there a new line after each like `Duration: 1 Month\nName: James Foo\nCategory: Info Tech`. After getting this info you will receive an answer.

Comment: Values are separated with <li>. @Cryptic already provided me the answer I was looking for but I don't mind you showing me your solution as well. I'd love to study the code for the sake of information and future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer regex you can do this:

```
$array = array('data' =>
'Duration: 1 Month
Name: James Foo
Category: Info Tech');

function get_line($array, $line)
{
    preg_match('/' . preg_quote($line) . ': ([^\n]+)/', $array['data'], $match);
    return $match[1];
}

echo get_line($array, 'Category');
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for this. How do you omit the 'category:' label and just echo the 'Info Tech'? Also, I would like to point out that the values inside [data] are in a list (<ul><li></li></ul>).

Comment: @xchampionx can you update your question with the raw text of print_r(), I think you copied and pasted from screen reason the HTML was not copied as well. I can easily modify my solution if I knew the correct format it is in.

Comment: @xchampionx, I'm heading out to eat dinner, but if I am correct on your format if you change the `\n` to `<` it should work. If not, I'll check back and modify solution based on your question update.

Comment: Thank you so much @cryptic. Worked wonders. The regex is specially useful as I can just switch between 'Duration', 'Name' and 'Category' easily. Not quite the case for the first two. The above solutions also worked with the <li> tag. So no problem here I thought it would be just worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($array as $k => $v)
    echo "Category: ".$v['Category']."\n";
```

Comment: I don't think the $v is an array but a large string. You would need to parse the string and extract that line.