# Get specific object-item from array

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I'm using the following function where `$task` is an array of `TaskData` instances

```
var_dump(array_pop($task));

// outputs when used repeatdly:
object(TaskData)[18]
  private 'id_task' => string '4' (length=1)
  private 'name' => null
  private 'process_id' => null

object(TaskData)[22]
  private 'id_task' => string '9' (length=1)
  private 'name' => null
  private 'process_id' => null

object(TaskData)[27]
  private 'id_task' => string '18' (length=2)
  private 'name' => null
  private 'process_id' => null

object(TaskData)[46]
  private 'id_task' => string '42' (length=2)
  private 'name' => null
  private 'process_id' => null

object(TaskData)[18]
  private 'id_task' => string '47' (length=2)
  private 'name' => null
  private 'process_id' => null

object(TaskData)[36]
  private 'id_task' => string '57' (length=2)
  private 'name' => null
  private 'process_id' => null

object(TaskData)[35]
  private 'id_task' => string '63' (length=2)
  private 'name' => null
  private 'process_id' => null

object(TaskData)[41]
  private 'id_task' => string '68' (length=2)
  private 'name' => null
  private 'process_id' => null

object(TaskData)[26]
  private 'id_task' => string '70' (length=2)
  private 'name' => null
  private 'process_id' => null
```

How can I access the id_task item (in the sample: `'4','9','18','42'`)?

Comment: is `TaskData` your own class?

Comment: Yes, I can modify it if needed. Why ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In PHP, is there a function that returns an array made up of the value of a key from an array of associative arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659875/in-php-is-there-a-function-that-returns-an-array-made-up-of-the-value-of-a-key)

Comment: @KenY-N Op here has an array of `TaskData` instances, which are not the same as accessing simple arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$task` seems to be an array of `TaskData` instances. the member you are trying to reach is private. a [read on visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)

```
private 'id_task'
```

if it were public it could be reached that way:

```
foreach ($task as $taskData) {
    var_dump($taskData->id_task);
}
```

[you're perfectly right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29407301/get-specific-object-item-from-array/29407739#comment46991426_29407739), setting a public getter for a private member is a way better idea:

```
public function getTaskID() {
    return $this->id_task;
}
```

Comment: I created a public function `public function getTaskID() {return $this->id_task;}`
And it works perfectly, thanks !